# Suggest an advanced text editor for Ubuntu

Tags: text-editor

I am looking for a text editor with advanced capabilities. For example; I should be able to expand and collapse xml codes/sections (or c/c++ sections) easily.

Something similar notepad++ for windows.

Also, If it can additionally create a Table of contents from the tags that would be even  more good!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898/text-editor-for-linux-besides-vi

Comment: This is sort of a 'Big List' question, as it genrally ends up with lots of answers as everyone has their own answer, so this might be closed as that, per the FAQ, despite being fairly useful like other [tag:software-recommendation] questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Geany](http://www.geany.org/) can do the collapsing. You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install geany
```

or from the Software Center.

Answer (score 7):

I use notepad++ on windows but since it is not avaible on linux I use [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Here is an list with linux text editors:
[link](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux%20text%20editors)

Comment: +1 for Sublime Text! It's absolutely fantastic!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not much of a GUI user but I love [**Kate**](http://lifehacker.com/5911460/the-best-programming-text-editor-for-linux) editor which is quiet good for programming purpose.

Comment: Kate is a fine editor, but since it is KDE based there are often issues running it on Unity. For example it has a habit of loading with the top bar of the window hidden by the Unity toolbar, so you have to switch workspaces, drag it to the center, and then move it back to the old workspace.

Answer (score 1):

[Gedit](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gedit/) if very good a C and other programming languages. It does highlighting, making it easy to use.

[Bluefish](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bluefish/)  is very good as well, and also does the collapse/expand behaviour you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using jEdit for LaTeX and python.  I find the syntax highlighting better than notepad++, and it does code folding, though I haven't tried it on C.
I was seriously considering trying notepad++ under wine though.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [QtCreator](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category%3aTools%3a%3aQtCreator#f61fd4c8f7d3f472707efe05d3a7ac47) only (probably without tool-chains and compilers). There are good code highlight and ability to customize syntax for yourself. Also, as you asked, QtCreator is able to create table of context + code completion.